# SOAP call response only getting last result - Python

Tags: python, api, soap, pycharm

this is the first time i am posting . So apologizing in advance if something is not in order . So based on the below python script i am trying to call a SOAP API and recording the response. Then iterating through that response to call another method with data from the first response. But print(data) only displaying the last row,not complete result set. I am new to Python .

```
def lambda_handler(): #event, context--------------------
   
    zsession = Session()
    zsession.verify = False
    url = 'TheURL'
    local_file_name="test.wsdl"
    transport = Transport(session=zsession)
    transport.load_timeout=2000
    client = Client(local_file_name, transport=transport)
    service = client.create_service(
        '{http://www.someurl.com', url)
 
    response = service.RetrieveRegionsByCriteria('*')
    
    content = ''
       for item in response:
     
        properties = service.RetrievePlanningSessionPropertiesByCriteria(criteria=item.regionIdentity.regionID)#item.regionIdentity.regionID))
        
    for property in properties:
          row_str ='{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}'.format(property.sessionIdentity.internalSessionID, GetStringValue(item.regionIdentity.regionID), GetStringValue(property.description), GetStringValue(property.scenario))
          
   
  data = ''
    data = data + row_str + "\n"
    print(data)
   
       print("Function completed successfully")
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.   Also, you have ```row_str = '{0}....```  That's going to overwrite your row_str.  are you trying to concatenate each row_str?

Answer (score 0):

You're using custom service methods in your code, so I don't know what data you are receiving.

One issue I noticed is that you keep overwriting the same variable (`row_str`) in the property loop.

Change this line:

```
for property in properties:
      row_str ='{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}'.format(property.sessionIdentity.internalSessionID, GetStringValue(item.regionIdentity.regionID), GetStringValue(property.description), GetStringValue(property.scenario))
```

To this:

```
row_str = ''
for property in properties:
      row_str +='{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}\n'.format(property.sessionIdentity.internalSessionID, GetStringValue(item.regionIdentity.regionID), GetStringValue(property.description), GetStringValue(property.scenario))
```